# apollo client nodejs query local state with filters

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

i'm using an apollo client in standalone node.js app.

**client** (there is no problem with client itself, so i think detailed `link`, `typeDefs`, `resolvers` configs are not so relevant):

```
apolloCli = new ApolloClient({
    link,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    typeDefs,
    resolvers
});
```

**queries:**

```
export const hubsQuery = gql`
    query HubsQuery {
        hubs {
            id
            ip
            port
            isOnline
        }
    }`;

export const hubsOnlineLocalQuery = gql`
    query HubsQueryLocal {
        hubs(isOnline: true) @client {
            id
            ip
            port
            isOnline
        }
    }`;
```

**usage:**

```
    const q0 = await apolloCli.query({query: hubsQuery, fetchPolicy: 'network-only'});
    console.log(q.data);


    const q1 = await apolloCli.query({query: hubsOnlineLocalQuery});
    console.log(r.data)
```

So, despite that `q0` was successfull and contains an array, the `data` returned from the `q1` is `null`.

My guess is:

1. some design flaw which i don't understand
2. local cache store data uniquely for each `query`.

I expect `q1` to return results from the local store filtered by `isOnline`
What could be the possible reason of `q1` data returning `null` and how to fix it?:)

Comment: You don't have to share all your local resolvers, but the one specifically for `hubs` is likely necessary for answering this question since that's where the problem most likely lies.

Comment: That said, assuming your resolver is written correctly, I've also never used a local field that shared a name with a remote field. It's possible for that to work given how Apollo resolves @client fields, but it also wouldn't surprise me if the name conflict was causing some unexpected behavior.

Comment: i didn't write the resolvers at all since i expect `q1` to query local cache, as it's written here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/local-state/#local-data-query-flow
it does work if i query `hubs @client` without specifying filter `(isOnline: true)`. So i thought since the query runs against the same collection, it must work without a resolver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apollo resolves fields with the `@client` directive by first looking for the relevant resolver, and if one doesn't exist, then looking for the data directly in the cache.

When queries are stored in the cache, they referenced not just by the field but also by the arguments that were passed to those fields. So the result of a query like `hubs(isOnline: true)` and `hubs(isOnline: false)` will be stored separately in the cache. Similarly `hubs(isOnline: true)` and `hubs` are separate queries and stored separately.

So, you do have some data in the cache, but it's effectively not associated with the `hubs(isOnline: true)` query you're trying to run.

Even if Apollo did pull from what's already in the cache automatically in this case, you'd *still* need a custom resolver because you're trying to implement some business logic (show only hubs that are online) and Apollo has no way of knowing how to implement that just based on the argument you're passing in.

In either case, the answer is to supply a custom resolver for the `hubs` field. Something like:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hubs: (obj, { isOnline }, { cache }) => {
      const { hubs } = cache.readQuery({ query: hubsQuery })
      return hubs.filter((hub) => hub.isOnline)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah that was my guess and solved it this way an hour ago :) haven't found how exactly does `apollo-client` searching a cache - i thought it would find a relevant entities based on `__typename`.